# SSH cannot connect from Remote computer after a while

Tags: debian, ssh

I can successfully connect to Debian via SSH.
The problem is that after a while — one or two days I think — it depends on the number of times I connect, I cannot connect remotely... **only locally**. The machine must be restarted in order to reconnect.

I haven't seen the error myself yet, as they restart it at 4am in the morning and I am not there, but it is like "networking down" ? "connection table ...something"...

Any ideas what I can do to trace/solve this problem ?

I get this also in the `sshd` log when it is down:

> debian exim4: gethostby*.getanswer:
>   asked for "debian IN AAAA", got type
>   "A"

Comment: Have you set `TCPKeepAlive Yes` in your `/etc/ssh/ssd_config`? And are you using a `ClientAliveInterval`?

Comment: I checked the logs of sshd and it is a mess. There are tons of computers trying to connect remotely.. I think i should change port or something.. TCPKeepAlive Yes  there is yes...  but i havent set iptables.. ClientAliveInterval there isnt such option..

Comment: Change your port. The log message looks to be an IPv6 request - I don't think it is related to your timeout issue...

Comment: This request occurs only when i have problem..

Comment: I guess that "I can connect *only locally*" means that you are no longer able to connect via SSH, only via login/physical keyboard access?  If this is correct, this sounds like a DHCP problem to me: the DHCP lease for the IP address expires and your box doesn't get a new one. Can you please post the output of `ip addr show` when you can connect and when you cannot?

Comment: locally i mean the local network... It is a NAT. But from local ip it can connect!  eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:85:64:d5:48:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.0.0.50/24 brd 100.0.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::d685:64ff:fed5:4806/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: @Parhs are you sure the IP address of your box is not changing, then? Maybe the router is still forwarding packets to the old IP address, that would explain why you cannot log in from remote but you can from the LAN.  How is the NAT set up?  Specifically, how is the router configured to forward packets to your box?

Comment: They told me that at the connection icon in GUI desktop there is a message network disconnected error but still locally works ..The ip of the sshd box is static and the internet ip is static... I have forwarded port 22...The router works fine i believe as it wont need restart

Comment: It looks like your NAT isn't noticing dropped connections, and eventually that connection table becomes full. You'll get better answers if you 1: describe your network topology precisely (what is between the local client and the server? what is between the remote client and the server?) and 2: report exact error messages (if you can't see them, have the person copy-paste them into an email or something; even better if you have access to logs).

Comment: i can have access but i dont know where to look.. i looked at /var/log nothing interesting... As i understood network mananager popuped with an error..The network topology is really simple.. A switch with 15 computers + a dsl router and a wifi router.

Comment: Probably already solved, but maybe this thread will help http://freebsd.1045724.n5.nabble.com/repeating-error-message-from-ssh-td3819498.html